# Newrelic exceptions still being logged

Tags: newrelic

Newrelic is logging exceptions generated by our application even though we have specified in the yaml file not to log particualr exceptions

We are using version 2.21.3 of the java agent

yaml is configured with

ignore_status_codes: 401,404,42

401 exceptions are still being logged (and alerted) in Newrelic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O2MA.jpg "screenshot of newrelic showing the error

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of improvements to error handling since 2.21.3 of New Relic's Java Agent, so if you're not using Java 5 the best first step to fix this is to update the agent. Release notes are at: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java